# Copying files with a Russian name into a container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, localization

I have asp.net core mvc application with Russian filenames in wwwroot. When copying to docker container the names are not displayed correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcL2k.png)
Then at the dotnet publish stage the error

```
"error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "/src/src/VL_APP.Web.Mvc/wwwroot/**" because it was not found."
```

occurs. As far as I suspect this is due to incorrect path to the file in the container.

The solution may be to rename the files to English and change the code base to work with the renamed files. This will work, but I am not satisfied with this solution, I need file names in Russian.

Attempts to work with localization in Dockerfile were not successful.

```
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Are there ways to solve this problem through localization in the container or some other ways?

Comment: Any feedback?  Has the answer below solved your problem?  If so remember [to approve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Tested with `ubuntu:latest`.  Note that with `alpine:latest` Russian filenames work by default.